# Try-catch short-circuit/fall-through java

Tags: java, exception

I want to use a try-catch block to handle two cases: a specific exception, and any other exception. Can I do this? (An example)

```
try{
    Integer.parseInt(args[1])
}

catch (NumberFormatException e){
    // Catch a number format exception and handle the argument as a string      
}

catch (Exception e){
    // Catch all other exceptions and do something else. In this case
    // we may get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
    // We specifically don't want to handle NumberFormatException here      
}
```

Will the NumberFormatException be handled by the bottom block as well?

Comment: Yes, I could, but this is useful to others as well, I hope. Also, davidbuzatto's addition has revealed a feature I didn't know about, so I've gained more from asking this question than I would through a simple test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, because the more specific exception (NumberFormatException) will be handled in the first catch. It is important to note that if you swap the catches you will get a compilation error, since you MUST specify the more specific exceptions before the more general ones.

It is not your case, but since Java 7 you can group exceptions in catch like:

```
try {
    // code that can throw exceptions...
} catch ( Exception1 | Exception2 | ExceptionN exc ) {
    // you can handle Exception1, 2 and N in the same way here
} catch ( Exception exc ) {
    // here you handle the rest
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If a `NumberFormatException` is thrown, it will be caught by the first `catch` and the second `catch` won't be executed. All other exceptions go to the second.

Answer (score -1):

try this: Added `throw new Exception()`  in **NFE** catch.

```
try{
    Integer.parseInt(args[1])
}

catch (NumberFormatException e){
    // Catch a number format exception and handle the argument as a string
    throw new Exception();      
}

catch (Exception e){
    // Catch all other exceptions and do something else. In this case
    // we may get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
    // We specifically don't want to handle NumberFormatException here      
}
```

In this way, You can handle **NFE** in its catch block. And all other in another block. You don't need to handle **NFE** again in second block.

Comment: This doesn't compile. The thrown Exception is outside of the original try catch and would need to be handled separately.